# Bash error : [: missing `]'

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, comparison, conditional-statements

I would like to implement a quite simple function but an error occurs on the condition used.

```
function test()
{   
    checkstatus
    echo ${currentStatus}
    if [ "$currentStatus" == "true" ] 
    then    
        echo "Currently Ok"
    else
        exit_error 101  
    fi
}
test
```

However the script returns :

true

./script.sh: line 4: [: missing `]'

Comment: Not actually looked properly but you should always use `[[...]]` over `[...]` unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: Most due to some stray carriage return/line feed in your file. You will also get an error if `currentStatus` is uninitialized.

Comment: How do you assign `currentStatus`? Does your first (shebang) line contain `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Yes the first line contains #!/bin/bash. The currenStatus is assigned by the function checkStatus which contains the following declaration currentStatus=${array[7]}

Comment: JID, your solution returns multiple errors : syntax error in conditional expression, syntax error near `]] ', `      if [[ "${currenStatus}" == "true" ]] '

Comment: I tried running your code by assigning some value to currentStatus since you have not given definition of _checkstatus_ function it is working fine. problem is either within _checkstatus_ function or _exit_error_ function

Comment: I tried running below piece of code                                               **function test()
{
    #checkstatus
    currentStatus="false"
    echo ${currentStatus}
    if [ "$currentStatus" == "true" ]
    then
        echo "Currently Ok"
    else
       echo "Not Ok"
        exit 1
    fi
}
test**

Comment: Try: `if [ "x$currentStatus" == "xtrue" ]`

Comment: @JID, never been a big fan of always use `[[...]]` over `[...]` from a portability standpoint. Further, the only operator supported in `[[...]]` not supported in `test` is the `=~` operator. Absent that, all using `[[...]]` over `test` does is relieve the user from having to learn to quote properly and limit portability to bash or bash.

Comment: There are a lot more differences than that, the one and only advantage of `[...]` is portability on old shells. If you are just using bash it is just all round worse. This may be useful reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: If line 4 is missing `[` then obviously the problem is with `checkstatus` function on line 3.Which we have no visibilty of so any effort to help would be futile.

Comment: JID, the checkStatus function just execute a dbus command and store the result in an array as array=($(dbus-send --system ... )) and the currentStatus=${array[7]}

Comment: David C. Rankin, your solution works is the condition is if [ "x$currentStatus" == "xtrue" ] but if I execute the same function by changing if [ "x$currentStatus" == "xfalse" ] the problem is still present.. I don't understand the goal of adding "x" before the variable

Comment: Also as the error says line 4, either this is the entire script and it does not actually contain `#!/bin/bash` or you are showing us some unrelated code.

Comment: After '[' do NOT add an space.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in /bin/sh comparison blocks should only have one '=' equal character when using single brackets if-block:

```
#!/bin/sh
test(){   
    checkstatus
    echo ${currentStatus}
    if [ "$currentStatus" = "true" ]; then    
        echo "Currently Ok"
    else
        exit_error 101  
    fi
}
test
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
function test(){   
    checkstatus
    echo ${currentStatus}
    if [[ "$currentStatus" == "true" ]]; then    
        echo "Currently Ok"
    else
        exit_error 101  
    fi
}
test
```

Comment: Well at least somebody has their thinking cap on tonight. It's not me.

Comment: That makes absolutely no difference, you can use either as OP has already stated they are using `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice... my fault